# Triggering in php mySql

Tags: php, triggers

Let I have a table as the following...

```
-----------------------------
| id    |  questions  | type |
------------------------------
```

Based on server time I want to pick 5 random rows from this table and place those into another table.And I want this to happen after every 15 minutes of the server time. I am using php mySql. How this can be done. Is there any way so that it will run in  localhost (I am using windows) and linux server. If anybody of you have the idea please help me.
Thanx

Comment: Sounds like you could use [cronjobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronjob)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have linux server and cronjob installed:

**STEP 1:** Open a Terminal Window

Once you have opened a terminal window, type in the following...

```
crontab -e
```

**STEP 2: Add a cron job**

At the end of the file paste one of the following to have your cron job run...

Every Minute:

```
* * * * * /path/to/php -f /absolute/path/to/script.php
```

Every Five Minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/php -f /absolute/path/to/script.php
```

Every Hour:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/php -f /absolute/path/to/script.php
```

Every Five Hours:

```
0 */5 * * * /path/to/php -f /absolute/path/to/script.php
```

**STEP 3: Save**

And in your php file you can do those manipulations you stated as you wish

Answer (score 0):

You need a scheduler. You can write a PHP script to program your requirement. Since you are running Windows, start your Windows Task Scheduler, add your script as the action.

If you were running Linux, you would be doing what @Vit Kos noted above.